# How to don't let the "APP" stuck while doing complex operations [Suggestion on App Performance]?

Tags: android

Actually i'm trying to make an app that will permise to take orders in a restaurant for waiter.

For now all is going well until i've added the possibility to "draw" the variant to a plate.  (Yes i know it's not a good practise and even usefull stuff but my boss said that he want it so i had to implement that stuff)

Actually in the app when i press "Draw Variant" it will open a small AlertDialog where the user is able to draw and when he press on Drawing Icon it put the image on the main RecyclerView and doing complex decoding operations with a lot of for and if's by decoding to Decimal and Base64 for making the "Drawed" image lighter to send to the printer / server.

the issue so is when i press that button because the app is like stuck for a while (some seconds but it's look's like a bug) i was going to but a ProgressLoader but it's not a good practise so how can i do that complex operation but still don't stuck the App? (The app stuck because is entering in hundred of for loops)

As you can see on the screen the right image is that what is going to be stuck (the one with the AlertDialog) while the second image is just to show you how the app looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, a drawing canvas loading should not take some seconds on modern devices, so your code needs to be optimized.

If you want to keep it you should at least make it non blocking. Check this out for a suitable solution: https://android.jlelse.eu/8-ways-to-do-asynchronous-processing-in-android-and-counting-f634dc6fae4e

I would suggest using a lightweight library for this, no need for reinventing the wheel.

- https://github.com/simplifycom/ink-android
- https://github.com/ajithvgiri/Canvas-Library

Comment: Actually i was using this library for draw https://github.com/ajithvgiri/Canvas-Library , is the lightweight better that the one i was using? and greate one article for the asynchronous processing

Comment: Nice, didn't have a chance to test one of them. Added it to answer

Comment: Your goal should be that there are no loading times for this task. If your code is too heavy optimize it or try using libraries with better performance.